# Configuring spring security to continue after connection exceptions using multiple non-mirrored LDAP servers

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-ldap

I have a successful configuration using Spring Security with Spring Boot that will check four different LDAP providers for the user credentials passed to it.  If the user is not present in the first server, then the second is checked and so on.  This works perfectly if all of the providers are available.  However, if one of the providers is down, then the authentication chain stops and spring returns a not-authorized exception.

The authentication is for a REST based service so using a failure handler to redirect to a different URL doesn't seem like it will help the situation.

I know about the urls property on the context source, but from what I can determine that is only used for failover to a mirrored LDAP server that has the same configuration as the primary LDAP server.  That is not the case in this configuration, each LDAP server has its own separate and distinct configuration.

I've checked multiple StackOverflow questions and the Spring documentation and archived forums.  All of the questions and configurations I have seen are either for a mirrored failover configuration or are essentially the same configuration that I have.

My current configuration and AuthenticationManager setup, configured via a Groovy class, looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()                                                   
            .and()
        .httpBasic()

    http.httpBasic().realmName("Service Authorization")
}


@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception {

    authManagerBuilder.ldapAuthentication()
        .userSearchFilter("${ldapExtConfig.userSearchFilter}")
        .contextSource().url("${ldapExtConfig.url}/${ldapExtConfig.baseDn}")
        .managerDn("${ldapExtConfig.managerDn}")
        .managerPassword("${ldapExtConfig.managerPassword}")

    authManagerBuilder.ldapAuthentication()
        .userSearchFilter("${ldapAmerConfig.userSearchFilter}")
        .contextSource().url("${ldapAmerConfig.url}/${ldapAmerConfig.baseDn}")
            .managerDn("${ldapAmerConfig.managerDn}")
            .managerPassword("${ldapAmerConfig.managerPassword}")

    authManagerBuilder.ldapAuthentication()
        .userSearchFilter("${ldapEmeaConfig.userSearchFilter}")
        .contextSource().url("${ldapEmeaConfig.url}/${ldapEmeaConfig.baseDn}")
        .managerDn("${ldapEmeaConfig.managerDn}")
        .managerPassword("${ldapEmeaConfig.managerPassword}")

    authManagerBuilder.ldapAuthentication()
        .userSearchFilter("${ldapApacConfig.userSearchFilter}")
        .contextSource().url("${ldapApacConfig.url}/${ldapApacConfig.baseDn}")
        .managerDn("${ldapApacConfig.managerDn}")
        .managerPassword("${ldapApacConfig.managerPassword}")

}
```

I could split this up into multiple war/jar files since Spring Boot is lightweight but that solution was rejected by the server managers.  Do I have to look at implementing a custom authentication provider and try to wrap the sequence of attempts?

Is there any way to configure Spring Security to continue trying the subsequent AuthenticationProviders if the first cannot connect?  I would think that this should be possible, otherwise the utility of being able to specify multiple types of providers is somewhat limited.  Thanks!

Update:  I've done some work to replicate this locally and I cannot get it to work as I think it should. Also I cannot get a log message even with the Spring Security logging set to DEBUG.  I am able to get some additional information in the JSON response that is being handed back to me though.  Hostnames are altered deliberately in the message below.

```
{
  "error": "Unauthorized",
  "message": "ldapserver:636; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: ldapserver:636 [Root exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: ldapserver]",
  "status": 401,
  "timestamp": 1404924353023
}
```

So what seems to be happening is that the Spring Security LDAP provider is wrapping the communications exception, not logging it, and automatically converting it into an Unauthorized exception.  This would not be the behavior that I would anticipate, especially since I have multiple providers specified in the configuration.

Update 2:  I know it says unknown host exception above.  I deliberately put in an incorrect host name for the first server in order to get a communications type of exception.  The same type of thing is what was happening when the network could not temporarily reach the server during testing.

Comment: My understanding of the `AuthenticationProvider` contract is that this should work as is (assuming that the providers throw an `AuthenticationException` and that one of them is successful). Maybe you can share some more details of what goes wrong (switch on debug logging and see what it tells you for instance).

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the relevant sections of the logs from the server admins.  I will try to replicate what was happening and report back if I can get it to happen.